# How to control each delete button on the every <li> tags. (asp.net) -Code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, onclick, code-behind

I've been trying to write an onclick function, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I wrote a function in page load() and it provides that when the pages loading, the data is coming from database. And that `<li>` and delete `buttons` creating right there. I mean I didn't write `<li>` or button tags. (You can see the structure on the screen shot, I'll share it here). I can insert the records, but now I need to delete it on that delete buttons.

In this case my problem is: I want to use an onclick function in code behind (or you can advice another way) which I can control that `<li>` (like selectedrow) and anchor `<a>`.

This is page load (creating `<li>`,`<a>` and `button`)

```js
for (int i = 0; i < db.machines.Length; i++) {
  li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
  ancor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
  btn = new Button();
  btn.Text = "Delete";
  btn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
  btn.Attributes.Add("class", "deleteButton");
  li.Controls.Add(btn);
  li.Attributes.Add("class", "list-group-item");
  newitem = db.machines[i];
  machineUl.Controls.Add(li);
  ancor.InnerText = newitem;
  li.Controls.Add(ancor);
}
```

```html
<div id="machineListId" class="panel">
  <ul id="machineUl" class="list-group" runat="server">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: share the code of the delete button from designer.

Comment: There is no code for delete button in designer. There is just "protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl machineUl;" about this section.

Comment: Sorry i cant share all project. I have contract with my company. It is now mine own project. I've looked in designer, there is nothing about delete button. Also i didnt create click function.

Comment: Just share this aspx page and codebehind of this. so i can help

Answer (score 0):

```
for(YourConditions)
{
   //add button 
  var button = new Button {ID = "ButtonID", Text = "Text"};
  button.Click += button_Click;
  li.Controls.Add(button)
}
```

Code behind function

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get ID of Calling button
       Button button = (Button)sender;
       string buttonId = button.ID;
    // do your next stuff
}
```

//Note: Make button ID unique in for loop.
Hope this helps!

Comment: @Furkan Pressed button mistakenly ... answer updated

Comment: It looks perfectly. I'm gonna try that now and i'll feddback to you. (I have 3 more section like this and i want to use the oneclick function for all of it-so it could take time :)) İ'll be back and thank u

Comment: Good luck Furkan :) I believe it'll work because it works :)

Comment: Hey again. I still cant und something. How im going to select that buttons <li> and <a>. I want to do something like that in onclick:

string machinename=**select.button.li.a.Text**;
db.SqlDeleteCommand(machinename);

Comment: I'd suggest to add a hidden field and put all values you need to get in that hidden field. On button click get values from relevant hidden field.  To get hidden field from place holder...HiddenField h = li.FindControl("HiddenFieldID") as HiddenField;

Comment: I cant change the structure now. Pls check out my answer in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked my old projects. In one of them there is gridview and there are linkbuttons in every row. In there rows creating with button (show the datas) like page load here. And i found CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MessageID")%>' this code in linkbutton' html. I had used that MessegeId in code behind. I think i can handle this problem something like this. So if someone have an idea about it, would be great. I'll be deal on it and waiting an answer from here.